# Can dependent variables appear in interaction terms in a system of simultaneous equations?

Tags: interaction, instrumental-variables, 2sls

Given a system of 2 equations with y1 and y2 the dependent variables:
\begin{align}
y1 &= a0 + a1x1 + a2(x2y2) + ... + e1  \tag 1  \\
y2 &= b0 + b1x1 + b2(x2y1) + ... + e2,  \tag 2
\end{align}
Is it possible to estimate this system other than as reduced form?

My software will produce a result if I estimate it using 2sls or 3sls with instruments for y1 and y2, but I am not confident the software recognizes the dependent variables on both sides of the equations.

Assume z1 is an instrument for y1 and z2 is an instrument for y2.  I think the first stage estimation in the software becomes (slightly abusing the notation):
\begin{align}
y1 &= a0 + a1x1 + a2(x2z2) + ... + e1. \tag 3  \\
y2 &= b0 + b1x1 + b2(x2z1) + ... + e2.  \tag 4
\end{align}
This does not seem appropriate to me, because the y1 and y2 on the left hand side have no instrument.  I am wondering if anyone has come across this problem and can either offer a solution, or assure me that this is a fatal violation of the 2sls assumptions.